# PCIe link training

Tags: serial, high-speed, pcie

I got few questions about PCIe link training procedure.

1. For Gen3, will the host and device link to each other with Gen1 speed first, and when link up, host will look for device's capability register bit to see if it supports higher speed, and then issue the speed change process, until the host and device are all running at Gen3 speed. Is that correct?
2. For preset setting, is it true that the host and device will automatically choose a best preset when link training?

Comment: I think this goes on superuser...

Comment: @Bradman175 no. No user of soft- or hardware will ever be confronted with the question of how the hardware negotiates operating mode. That must happen under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that's pretty much right.  The PCIe link will come up as gen 1 and detect the number of available lanes.  Then the operating system can look at what the devices are capable of and request a speed change by writing to a control register.  The actual retraining is mediated by hardware.  The autonegotiation process will attempt to get to the highest supported speed and the largest supported link width (not just supported at the end points, but also by the backplane connections).

Comment: Is PCIe like a DMA engine with respect to functionality? Taking data from host and transferring to a IO

Comment: PCIe is just a protocol for transferring memory read and write requests and completions.  Direct memory access (DMA) is just a generic term to describe a device other than the CPU performing a memory read or write against some other component, either the host memory (traditional DMA) or another device (peer-to-peer DMA) over some interface, which could be PCIe.  It is common for a DMA engine to have a PCIe interface, but other interfaces are also possible.  The CPU can also initiate operations over PCIe, in which case it is not considered DMA.

Comment: So, DMA engine uses PCIe protocol to transfer data from one enpoint to another endpoint. Correct? PCIe is just like any other porotocol like uart,Can etc. It just takes the data provided by the host and sends it across to the destination.

Comment: Well, sort of.  It might be better to compare PCIe to something like UDP.  It cannot move arbitrary data, the data has to have particular headers attached (address, length, device ID, tag, etc.) to be handled correctly.